# How to convert linear grammar to Finite state machine

Tags: compiler-construction, discrete-mathematics, state-machine

I should convert linear right grammar to the finite-state machine.
The grammar is

```
S —> bA|aD|bC
А —> aC|bA
C —> bB|aA|b
B —> aD|bC|a
D —> aA|aC
```

Usually the problem is solved as follows:
To each state we associate the non-terminal. If there is a transition from X to Y by the state and, we add a rule X → aY. To add the final state rule X → ε. For ε-transitions - X → Y.

For example:

```
A → aB | cC
B → bD | cE
C → ε
D → aB | cC
E → aB | cC
```

[image: Solution]

Questions.

1. How to be if there is a connection A and A, for example, A -> aC |
   **bA**.
2. How to deal with structures C -> bB | aA | **b**, the end is only b.

Answer (score 2):

1] You can make self loops (e.g. Node Z can add letter o and then go to Node Z)

2] Use a trap state. You can't move anywhere from there but it still takes a move (and thus a letter) to get there

Comment: @tbutton no problem. If it helps you out, feel free to mark the answer as helpful ;)